# As google maps is not supported in China, I want to disable the component of Google maps because Im getting google undefined from an import

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps

I want to be able to not import a component in `module.ts` when the Google maps script is not working specifically in China.

My web interface is mainly based on tracking locations and it's used by European clients and also Chinese.

For the Chinese user, the web interface is completely white, and in the console, there is google undefined famous error and that's because one of my components is importing markers from google library which is not accessible in China...

So my question is : is there a way to exclude the import of my custom component in angular when the user is using a browser from China? Like a conditional import...

Comment: share what you tried? if possible a stackblitz?

Comment: do you mean the modules import or the import statement on top of a components file?

Comment: I mean the module import in app.module.ts , basically that costum component depends alot on google maps so I want to exclude it from the modules so that angular doesnt check it and fire errors of undefined google bla bla :( when the costumer is in china

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can just conditionally push the Module.

```
const myModulesToBeImported = [
  MyFooModule,
  MyBarModule
];

if (myFeatureAvailabilityCheck()) {
  myModulesToBeImported.push(MyGoogleMapsModule);
}

@NgModule({
imports: myModulesToBeImported,
```

---

**Edit: Example with environment**

environment.prod.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  condtionalModules: [MyGoogleMapsModule],
};
```

environment.cn.prod.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  condtionalModules: [],
};
```

app.module.ts

```
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
      MyFooModule,
      MyBarModule,
      ...environment.conditionalModules,
    ],
```

Comment: thank you for helping :) Im facing another issue now :(
I still need to somehow import the module even if I'm not using it in the NgModule:
--> import { MapViewComponent } from './map-view/map-view.component';
 di you know a way to tell angular to ignore checking the imports until they are used in NgModule imports ?

Comment: In theory you can call the import statement inline `import(pathToModule)` but that is an async operation, which would fail here.

Per your comment your module doesn't seems to be available at all. That means, that is likely due to some environment setting. If you have for example a environment.eu.prod.ts and a environment.cn.prod.ts, then you could define the to be condtional imported module there.

Comment: Added example in my answer